Pythonic way of dumping a valid JSON string as JSON
Suppose I have a valid JSON string that I want to make part of a larger JSON object. The most straightforward solution is parsing the string as dict, then dumping it again to JSON:
import json

json_str = '{"name": "Alice", "age": 30}'

# Write the JSON-encoded string to a string
new_json_str = json.dumps({"foo": "bar", "user": json.loads(json_str)})

Is the parsing - dumping round trip avoidable?
I'm trying to avoid the inverse of how to convert string json inside a valid json into valid json python

For a simple example you could just do e.g. f'{{"foo": "bar", "user": {json_str}}}', but for anything more complex you can't really say "don't serialise this bit", no.

Looking at the JSON spec, that might actually work in general. The formatting may be terrible, but I can't easily come up with a counter example.

It might "work", but it will be very prone to creating malformed results as you're making no validation at any step. Unless your JSON string is huge and parsing it takes noticeable amount of time, I'd say just parse it, modify as an object and dump again. It's not something you should be doing too often anyway.

With "work" I mean this procedure will produce a valid JSON string, given the inserted string is valid JSON and is inserted in place of a JSON value.
This should be provable.

You could insert a placeholder then do a simple string replace.
To avoid any chance of the placeholder conflicting with real data, I'm attaching a UUID.
from uuid import uuid4

placeholder = f'PLACEHOLDER_{uuid4()}'
json_with_placeholder = json.dumps({"foo": "bar", "user": placeholder})
new_json_str = json_with_placeholder.replace(json.dumps(placeholder), json_str)

Result:
'{"foo": "bar", "user": {"name": "Alice", "age": 30}}'


I can't think of any caveats to this. Given that json_str is valid JSON, I don't think it's possible to output malformed JSON.
I can only think of upsides, like that json_str will be preserved even if it doesn't follow Python object semantics, like duplicate names or float precision, e.g.
json_str = '{"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "age": 30.00000000000000000001}'


I like the uuid idea. Write a custom json decoder that anytime it sees an object that can't be converted to dict, instead of jsonifying it, it pushes it to a dict and inserts a placeholder. Then we iterate through the json template and replace any placeholder with the json representation of the object.
